# how to call C++ overloaded function from C macros

Tags: c++, c, overloading, variadic-functions

I'm adding a macro used in C file which should take a variable number of arguments, which should be handled based on the type and the number of arguments differently. If it's pure C++, it's easily achieved by overloading the function, but how would I pass the variadic arguments from C macro into C++ with this mixture of C and C++?

The C file is restricted to be compiled with gcc. In macro definition, I passed the variadic arguments into C wrapper function. Since the number of arguments is unknown, I have a macro counting the arguments and pass it along into va_list. But using this approach, I do not know the type of arguments to flexibly pass any arguments to C++ function. I'm including relevant code snippet reflecting the current structure of code, skipping the actual handling logic in cpp file and other irrelevant information.

In use.c:

```
#include "macro.h"
LOG(id, lvl, params);
```

In macro.h:

```
#define LOG(_MSG_ID_, _LOG_LVL_, ...) \
  log_data(&hdr, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
```

In logger.h:

```
#define GET_NARG(_1, _2, _3, _4, N, ...) N
#define COUNT_VARARGS(...) GET_NARG(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)
#define log_data(p_hdr, ...) \
  log_data_c(p_hdr, COUNT_VARARGS(__VA_ARGS__), ##__VA_ARGS__);

#ifdef __cplusplus
class LOGGER
{
 public:
  void log_data(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr);
  void log_data(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint16_t val);
  void log_data(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint64_t val);
  void log_data(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint32_t val1, uint32_t val1);
  // and other overloaded functions
  static inline LOGGER& getInstance() { return m_instance; }
 private:
  static LOGGER m_instance;
};
#else
typedef struct LOGGER LOGGER;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern void log_data_c(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, int n, ...);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In logger.cpp:

```
#include "logger.h"
#include <stdarg.h>

LOGGER LOGGER::m_instance = LOGGER();
#define LOGGER_Instance LOGGER::getInstance()

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void log_cmn_data(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, int n, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);
  LOGGER_Instance.log_data(va_arg(args, LOG_HEADER_s*));
  va_end(args);
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The ideal scenario would be just passing the variadic arguments in the macro into the invocation of C++ overloaded function. Any workarounds to achieve the result are welcome. I've been trying to get this working for a while but I haven't found a post dealing with the same scenario. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot call overloaded C++ functions from C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm probably mistaken, but I was assuming that there's some `struct LOGGER`, given its use in a `typedef` in the C part, which causes some ambiguity (to me) as to OP's intentions.

Comment: OK, never mind. I think I see now. You're trying to have a type-safe printf-like function in C like you can have in C++? That's not possible. Macros aren't gonna help you. You need to pass a format string, just like `printf()` has, to tell the function what types the arguments have.

Comment: Not a problem exactly, but `#ifdef __cplusplus` blocks in a C++ file is just clutter.

Comment: Are you planning to build that logger.cpp separately with C and C++ compilers, or why do you have that #ifdef __cplusplus there?

Comment: Anyway, you want `extern "C"` functions in C++ (meaning code compiled with C++ compiler). From those you can call normal C++ functions (which are name-mangled for linker, and support overloading etc). You can't call normal C++ functions from C (meaning code compiled with C compiler) directly (at least not practically/sanely), you can only call `extern "C"` functions (and those don't support overloading, can't be methods etc limitations of C language).

Comment: Why cannot you use your LOG macro to call your function directly? Why do you need a wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

> Since the number of arguments is unknown, I have a macro counting the
>   arguments and pass it along into va_list. But using this approach, I
>   do not know the type of arguments to flexibly pass any arguments to
>   C++ function.

That's right, you don't know.  The C mechanism for variadic functions does not directly provide the called function any information about the number or types of the variable arguments.  The called function must use a combination of assumptions and information gleaned from its arguments to make that determination.  The `printf` function is the canonical example: it determines both the number of variable arguments and their types by analyzing the the provided format string (and havoc ensues if the arguments actually provided are mismatched with the format).

Provided that you place a fixed, artificial upper limit on the number of variable arguments supported, you can indeed count them via a variadic macro, as demonstrated.  Very little type information is available to the preprocessor, however, and there is no applicable mechanism for applying what little such information there is to your purpose.

The usual C alternative to function overloading is simply to write functions with different names.  If you have similar functions that differ primarily in parameter number and type, then you might give them related names that convey those types.  For example,

```
void log_data(LOG_HEADER_s *);
void log_data_u16(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint16_t);
void log_data_u64(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint64_t);
void log_data_u32_u32(LOG_HEADER_s* hdr, uint32_t, uint32_t);
```

Alternatively, it might be more appropriate to give them names that convey the purpose of their particular signature.  I'm inclined to suspect that an approach along these lines would work better for you than trying to multiplex your several distinct logging functions through a single variadic interface.

On the other hand, if you insist on providing a single variadic function interface, then you could put multiple for-purpose macros in front of it on the C side, each corresponding to one of the supported back-end signatures.  These would not need to be variadic (unless the corresponding specific function was).  This would be to your advantage because you would get at least argument-count validation from your compiler (for calls going through the macros), and they could provide whatever extra arguments are needed to convey the expected number and types of arguments to the variadic interface function.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion. C function with slightly different names is the convention for C "overloading" and that's the first thing that came to my mind. The challenge I face here is that inside macro, I'll need to invoke functions with different names based on variables, which I couldn't think of an optimal way. Do you have suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @caly, if you provide functions with different names, then I don't see why you need a macro at all.  But if you want one, whether in that case or your original case, then my last paragraph suggests providing several for-purpose macros instead of one generic one that tries to figure out what to do from its argument list.  This is, of course, along the same lines as providing separate function names and using them directly.

Comment: What do you mean by for-purpose macros? What I'm trying right now is that I pass in parameter type as an enum to the macro and try to do an if-else on the type and call corresponding C functions with different names. Since the number of parameters is different, the compiler is complaining about too few arguments for some of the cases. Which part am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @caiy, what you're doing wrong is trying to do too much with a single macro. "Multiple for-purpose macros" would be a separate macro for each purpose -- that is, for each different argument pattern you want to support.